# Can you please turn this site into a fatwa and Q&A?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I forgot to ask you a small favor in first place. I had [posted](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43245/23833) a question, and someone told me that this is a fatwa and we all know that fatwas are forbidden in this site due to unknown reasons.

But, may I ask you to do a small favor for me? And that is to make this site to be a fatwa and in the same time to be a question and answer site just like that site [**Islamqa Q&A**](https://islamqa.info/en) is. What do you say? Are you **agreed** or **disagreed** with this idea?

**P.S.** Please comment below your justifications for each answer you make, for they are relevant and significant. If are you agreed, can you please ask also(if it is possible) to those on **Meta Stack Exchange** for new update? The reason I have asked this, is because somewhere in my post I think, you have said that you do not have power to do yourselves the update, so can you ask on Meta for this?

Answer (score 6):

This is a terrible idea.

- ***Maybe* it would work if questioners on the whole could write clear and focused questions**: As it stands, the majority of fatwa questions simply ask what "Islam" says about something as if there's any single unambiguous answer, ignoring the fact that there's over fourteen centuries of differing opinions and schools of thought on pretty much every topic imaginable.
- ***Maybe* it would work if answerers on the whole had the basic critical skills and training to actually formulate a fatwa and the recognized authority to do so**: As it stands, the majority of fatwa answers simply copy and paste already written fatawa from other sites as if they were universally applicable to all situations and all madhahib, or even posting segments of mutually exclusive fatawa in the same answer and formulating a new ruling that nobody actually follows.
- ***Maybe* it would work if the community on the whole had healthy voting practices that ensured that correct and useful answers rise to the top and incorrect and useless answers sink to the bottom**: As it stands, proper voting — up and down — is very limited on this site and often overwhelmed by users simply voting based on opinions they agree with regardless of how well-written or useful it is to the question.

**But that's three *very big maybes***. Even if all these conditions were met, it would still require the community to ensure that these questions and answers stay constructive, which would be a significant effort given the sheer quantity of non-constructive posts that such questions would attract; quite frankly, given how often this topic was brought up in the past to little to no enthusiasm, that's just not something the community is willing to do.

Without those three factors and a community willing to enforce them, all you'll be getting is a bunch of people who don't know what they're asking for getting a bunch of opinions from people who don't know what they're talking about with no way to determine which one is better than any other.

If that's what you want, there's already plenty of Islamic forums out there which do that. We want this site to be not that because — given how often those same questions are getting asked with nobody agreeing on an answer — that was obviously not working.

Comment: So, the first link I posted was clear or did that post is correct made? I mean, if it is 100% clear, focused and without errors.

Answer (score -3):

It is a fatwa site without a doubt. Fatwa word comes from triliteral root fā tā yā (ف ت ي) which means answering, ruling, explaining, advising, inquiring.