# Can we get a disclaimer on the site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Other religious sites on the Stack Exchange network display a notice on the top right of their website which essentially tells users that that the site does not offer personal advice.

Some examples:

[Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)

> Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi.

[Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)

> Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

[Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)

> Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor.

[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) and [Medical Science](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) also have similar notices.

I was thinking that we should also display such a notice on Islam.SE. Every now and then we get questions that ask for advice or legal verdicts on their real life personal issues. For example people ask for advice on whether they should divorce their spouse or ask for a legal verdict on whether their divorce or marriage is valid. Having the notice might help mitigate some of these queries.

Here is a mock up notice based on the pattern of the other sites:

> Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor.

Comment: Yeah, given how dead meta is at the best of times, I doubt this is going to receive any more activity (positive or negative). I'mma kick it up to the community team as-is and see what they make of it.

Comment: I've vetted this change & submitted it to be added to the site. (cc @goldPseudo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've added this to the site:

[image: Sidebar reading "Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor."]

Answer (score 2):

Each of the existing examples of disclaimers also include a link to a meta post and/or article with further details on the how and why. Here are a few links from our own meta that might be valuable (either on their own as direct links, or compiled into a new canonical meta thread that can be linked instead):

- [A higher standard for "fatwa" questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/383/22)
- [We need to set a standard for fatwa questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1422/22)
- [Can you please turn this site into a fatwa and Q&A?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3405/22)

I am leaving this answer Community Wiki so if anyone else digs up more feel free to include them.